# Leaderboard command not working for my economy bot discord.py

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make an economy bot (I'm following a tutorial), and all is working apart from my 'leaderboard' command.
Here is the code:

```py
@client.command(aliases = ["lb"])
async def leaderboard(ctx,x = 1):
    users = await get_bank_data()
    leader_board = {}
    total = []
    for user in users:
        name = int(user)
        total_amount = users[user]["wallet"] + users[user]["bank"]
        leader_board[total_amount] = name
        total.append(total_amount)

    total = sorted(total,reverse=True)

    em = discord.Embed(title = f"Top {x} Richest People" , description = "This is decided on the basis of raw money in the bank and wallet",color = discord.Color(0xfa43ee))
    index = 1
    for amt in total:
        id_ = leader_board[amt]
        member = client.get_user(id_)
        name = member.name
        em.add_field(name = f"{index}. {name}" , value = f"{amt}",  inline = False)
        if index == x:
            break
        else:
            index += 1

    await ctx.send(embed = em)


async def open_account(user):

    users = await get_bank_data()

    if str(user.id) in users:
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0

    with open('mainbank.json','w') as f:
        json.dump(users,f)

    return True


async def get_bank_data():
    with open('mainbank.json','r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    return users


async def update_bank(user,change=0,mode = 'wallet'):
    users = await get_bank_data()

    users[str(user.id)][mode] += change

    with open('mainbank.json','w') as f:
        json.dump(users,f)
    bal = users[str(user.id)]['wallet'],users[str(user.id)]['bank']
    return bal
```

The code is supposed to show the top people with the highest balance. It doesn't give me any error on startup or when I enter the command.

Comment: Do you have the necessary intents? Have you enabled them in your Discord Developer Portal? Do you have an `on_message` event listener (`async def on_message(<ctx>)`)? If you do, do you process the commands using `bot.process_commands(<ctx>)`?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to trim the code down to a [mcve]. Debugging is a crucial step and can sometimes point you directly to the answer, or at least make it easier for others to help you solve your problem.

Comment: What's the error? Can you add the full traceback of it?